# Get Json data in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

There is not a single clear example that explains how to pull json data as simple as possible. I have a valid json and I need to retrieve it with jQuery

my json output is as:

```
{
    "title": "blog entries",
    "items" : [
        {
            "title": "Can Members of the Diaspora Work Effectively at th",
            "date": "8/4/2009 9:42:38 AM"
        },
        {
            "title": "Ashoka Brazil",
            "date": "7/15/2009 8:56:12 AM"
        },
        {
            "title": "Life Spring Hospital",
            "date": "7/15/2009 8:56:12 AM"
        },
        {
            "title": "Pozitron/Endeavor",
            "date": "5/26/2009 8:58:39 PM"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried retrieving it with the following but no luck.

```
    $.getJSON({
        type: "GET",
        data: { PROCESS: "ViewBlog" },
        url: "http://www.pangeaadvisors.org/sep123/blog.cs.asp",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json) {
            $(json).find('item').each(function(){
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                $('<div class="news_title"></div>').html(title).appendTo('#news_wrap');
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

**Its failing due to your url having 2 dots in the url**

Assuming the request is working (check firebug to see if the request goes out as a script tag & the response comes back) you will need to do

```
$.each( json.items, function(){

   ...

});
```

or you can use normal js

```
for (var i=0; i<json.items.length; i++) {

   ...

}
```

Comment: still nothing. see it yourself: http://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/students/organizations/sec/conference2009/blog.htm

Comment: Can you use the full jquery version so i can debug. The min version makes it hard!

Comment: also you dont need to pass the type and datatype for the getJson function

Comment: thats not the issue however, it fails on a regex with that url

Comment: replaced jquery with full version. also, removed gettype and type. still not working. Is there a way to fix the problem?

Comment: its the two dots in your file name

Comment: blog.cs.asp ? how can I replace it to blogcs.asp but I cant remove the second one. File wont work?

Comment: no idea what stack your on. Why cant you rename it? I dont get you

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$.getJSON("http://www.pangeaadvisors.org/sep123/blog.cs.asp",{ PROCESS: "ViewBlog" }, function(json) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        var title = json[i].Title;
                        $('<div class="news_title"></div>').html(title).appendTo('#news_wrap');
                    }
            });
```

as redsquare answered you need for or $.each :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look at how to make cross domain calls with ajax.  Making the request like this will be denied by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var items = test.items;
$.each(items,function(index,items){
    console.log(items.title); /// and items.date
})
```