# loop through json with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some json-code with has multiple objects in it, as such:

[image]

These are the values inside the object:

[image]

This is the json-code:

```
[{"pk_records_id":"34","record_artist":"Bouncing Souls","record_title":"How I Spent My Summer Vacation","record_added_date":"2011-05-05 17:36:34","record_category":"punkrock","record_price":"11.00","record_cover_link":"img\/Bouncing Souls-How I Spent My Summer Vacation.jpg","record_amount_sold":null,"record_amount_stock":"400","record_description":"A great follow-up to Hopeless Romantic"},{"pk_records_id":"4","record_artist":"Descendents","record_title":"Everything Sucks","record_added_date":"2011-03-11 00:00:00","record_category":"punkrock","record_price":"12.00","record_cover_link":"img\/descendents_everything_sucks.jpg","record_amount_sold":"3124","record_amount_stock":null,"record_description":null}]
```

And this is the code I try to use, so I would be able to retrieve the values (obviously):

```
success: function(obj_records){
    $.each(obj_records, function(index, value) {
        alert(obj_records.index.pk_records_id); 
    });             
}
```

But this doesn't work. How can I retrieve the data?

Edit:

If I use this code, I get an array for every single character in my json-code.

```
$.each(obj_records, function(index, value) {        
    alert(index + " : " + value);     
});
```

Comment: can u please paste you json data not the image, so that we can work on that.

Comment: still u use images? why don't you write manually, is this homework?? see the similar question  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241068/help-needed-retrieving-json-data-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with

```
for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
   alert("JSON Data: " + json[i].pk_records_id);
  // you need to write each key name here
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HW4j8/1/)

Comment: Very strange, it works in your demo, when I implement it I have an infinite amount of alerts that say "Undefined".

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you're accessing the result incorrectly.

Try:

```
success: function(obj_records){
    $.each(obj_records, function(index, value) {
        alert(value.pk_records_id); 
    });             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure (not in a place to test it), but I think you want:

```
success: function(obj_records){
    $.each(obj_records, function(index, value) {
        alert(value.pk_records_id); 
    });             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive what you want is this:

```
success: function(obj_records){
    $.each(obj_records, function(index, value) {        
        alert(value.pk_records_id);     
    });             
}
```

the `value` parameter inside the function header is the individual object of the `obj_records` array that you are looping over.

Comment: I get an infinite number of popups, all saying undefined.

Comment: Veltar, since your example provided an alert inside a loop, I am only editing based on your example.  Having an alert inside a loop will create a lot of messages, the same as the number in your array.

Comment: Rory, I'm sorry but your method is incorrect.  The obj_records is the array, not the individual object in the array.  Please reference the jquery api: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Now the OP has edited to include his JSON you are correct. I will remove my comment.