# Jquery .find works with xml but not JSON

Tags: xml, json, jquery

This works fine with XML

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/123/playlists.xml?client_id=ID",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: parse
            });
        });

        function parse(xml) {
           $(xml).find("playlists").each(function(){
                        //var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                        $("#catTitle").append($(this).text()+ "<br />"); 
                    });
        } 
        ​
```

but when I change it to this, it doesn't work. I put an alert() after `$(json).find("playlists").each(function(){` and it never gets called. Any thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/123/playlists.json?client_id=ID",
            dataType: "json",
            success: parse
        });
    });

    function parse(json) {
       $(json).find("playlists").each(function(){
                    //var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                    $("#catTitle").append($(this).text()+ "<br />"); 
                });
    } 
​
```

Comment: You can't search `json` with jQuery, it's a javascript object or array. Use it like a javascript object or array.

Comment: Yeah I have a thought, why do you expect it to work? It's not meant for XML either, it just happens that XML has enough of a similar structure to HTML to trick JQuery

Comment: json is not formatted to work with .find() method which use tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function parse(json) {
   $.each(json.playlists,function(idx,el){
       $("#catTitle").append(el+ "<br />"); 
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks - that's sort of what I ended up doing  `var items = [];
         var content = null;
         $.getJSON('http://api.soundcloud.com/users/123/playlists.json?client_id=[Client ID]',function(data) {
          content = data;
         }); 
    
    function parse(json) {
    $.each(content, function (index, item) {
        if (item.genre == type){
    
           //rest of function here
          }
        }
    };`

Answer (score 4):

That's not something jQuery is designed to do. If you want to work with an object or array defined by JSON, use that object or array directly.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Why has it worked for this person: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241068/help-needed-retrieving-json-data-with-jquery